# Python: Using multiprocessing when the function called is dependent on a file

Tags: python

I have a very old fortran file, which is too complex for me to convert into python. So I have to compile the file and run it via python.

For the fortran file to work it requires 3 input values on 3 lines from the `mobcal.run` file. They are as follows:

```
line 1 - Name of file to run
line 2 - Name of output file
line 3 - random seed number
```

I change the input values per worker in the `run()` function. 
When I run my script (see below), only 2 output file were created, but all 32 processers were running which i found out via the `top` command

I'm guessing the issue is here, is that there was not enough time to change the `mobcal.run` file for each worker.

The only solution I have come up with so far is to put a `time.sleep(random.randint(1,100))` at the beginning of the `run()` function. But I dont find this solution very elegant and may not always work as two workers may have the same `random.randint`, is there a more pythonic way to solve this?

```
def run(mfj_file):
        import shutil
        import random
        import subprocess
        #shutil.copy('./mfj_files/%s' % mfj_file, './')
        print 'Calculating cross sections for: %s' % mfj_file[:-4]
        with open('mobcal.run', 'w') as outf:
                outf.write(mfj_file+'\n'+mfj_file[:-4]+'.out\n'+str(random.randint(5000000,6000000)))

        ccs = subprocess.Popen(['./a.out'])
        ccs.wait()

        shutil.move('./'+mfj_file[:-4]+'.out', './results/%s.out' % mfj_file[:-4])



def mobcal_multi_cpu():
        from multiprocessing import Pool
        import os
        import shutil
        mfj_list = os.listdir('./mfj_files/')

        for f in mfj_list:
                shutil.copy('./mfj_files/'+f, './')

        if __name__ == '__main__':
                pool = Pool(processes=32)              
                pool.map(run,mfj_list)       


mobcal_multi_cpu()
```

Comment: So `mobcal.run` is hard coded into the fortran file? Is it possible to change where the fortran process reads its input?

Comment: It is hard coded in the fortran file, it uses the line variables multiple times in the fortran file. I have no knowledge of how to program in fortran so I guess I cant change where the fortran file reads the input variables.

Comment: Right, then I would go with @Steve answer below, just remember to copy `a.out` to the temp dir and copy the results out of the temp dir before finishing each subprocess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `a.out` looks in the current working directory for its `mobcal.run`. If you run each instance in it's own directory then each process can have it's own `mobcal.run` without clobbering the others. This isn't necessarily the most pythonic way but it's the most unixy.

```
import tempfile
import os

def run(mjf_file):
    dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=".")
    os.chdir(dir)

    # rest of function here
    # create mobcal.run in current directory
    # while changing references to other files from "./" to "../"
```

Comment: can you complete your example with copying `a.out` to the temp dir and the results out of there when done

Comment: You don't need to copy `a.out` to the temp dir (unless it's doing weird things), should be able to just run it as `"../a.out"`.

Comment: oh yes I see change the working directory to the temp dir, clever (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Create several directories, with one mobcal.run each, and run your fortran program into them instead.

If you need a sleep() in multiprocessing you are doing it wrong.